# Google Tag Manager script injection

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have recently been tasked with cleanup of our GTM tags. I notice that a lot of the tags include remote scripts by injecting them into the DOM using JS, for example:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
var js = document.createElement('script');
js.src = 'https://cdn.somewhere.com/script.js';
head.appendChild(js);
```

Is there a specific reason why people do it this way instead of just using this?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.somewhere.com/script.js" async></script>
```

What are the benefits of doing it the first way? Is there a better way to handle external scripts?

Comment: Well... could it be a requirement to only load them after user does a cookie consent?

Answer (score 3):

I found only one reason to do so but not sure if that is still actual nowadays. As said in [this article](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/add-html-elements-page-programmatically/) GTM strips some script attributes and if it's required to have them it's better to add the script programmatically.

Comment: That's actually a really good point, since e.g. some marketing tags will not work properly without their proprietary attributes.

Answer (score 1):

With GTM, there isn't really a point. The idea behind append script elements to the head is to affect load order, but since you first need to load GTM, which then injects the create element/append code into an arbitrary position before it runs, with GTM this otherwise sensible approach just creates an unnecessary extra step.

It's moot in any case, because these days you would neither use create/append, nor script tags in a Custom HTML tag. The way to go now is to create a custom template and use the [injectScript](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#injectscript) API.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for showing me this. I didn't realise GTM had custom template functions (still learning). So for this all you would need to do is have the tag be Custom HTML and call it like: `injectScript('https://cdn.somewhere.com/script.js')`? Are success and error callbacks optional?

Comment: You need at least the success callback. The error callback is useful if you want to use this in tag sequences, if you want to fire your follow-up tag only when the script has been successfully loaded. For injectScript to work you also need to set permissions in the template - this is a security feature to allow only certain origins for a script, to that this can't be used to load malicious scripts.

Answer (score 0):

With the second code you write it in the document in not specific position (or defined by GTM), instead with appendChild appends the element to the specified element (in this case `head`).

Answer (score 0):

Another use case for this approach is when someone hasn't got access to source code but they want to run scripts. It's kind of hacking because site owner might not even know the scripts are there. Could be legitimate use as well, i.e. a 3rd party hosted website where the site manager hasn't got permission to source code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you may do this is to **speed up website loading.**

By loading scripts after page load, you can significantly increase your PageSpeed Insights score.

Here is an example where the developer used Google Tag Manager to load livechatinc.js (a notoriously slow script) after page load:

[Load livechatinc code after webpage is fully loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55614515/load-livechatinc-code-after-webpage-is-fully-loaded)

Unfortunately, using Google Tag Manager adds ~300ms to your page load speed over Universal Analytics. But generally, this 300ms is far smaller than a script like Live Chat Inc's which can add 1-2 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason can be consent, as EU is strict about adding trackers, you can either implement your own consent control or you can do it via Google Tag Manager. And there you can control which script requires consent to be loaded up.

Another thing is - if you do the script via the GTM then you don't need to re-deploy your website.

It depends on how you manage GTM and if you have all the tags documented and a nice process about it. If you don't it can become really ugly really fast :)